# ?Question from a Computer Engineer?

Tags: modeling

:)
I am a retired (Sort of retired) Electrical and Computer and Graphics Artist soon to start my PhD in Physics. Something I really don't understand. Why is "Draw Curves" broke? I use the switching back and forth from Object Edit draw curve to get it to work. Leave a curve in a start up file I can just delete. That is a bit faster. Are you planning a major re-write of Blender? Only reason I could think of for just not fixing it? Just curious! :) Oh! I am running Ubuntu. The latest! 
Thank You for your time!
Steven Nerad

Comment: Hi, welcome to the Blender Stack Exchange! What do you mean by "Draw Curves"? A little more detail would help immensely.

Comment: This site is not officially affiliated with Blender. As such, we are not the developers. Any questions about development should be directed towards them.